# How to return a task from synchronous code for a mock implementation

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have little experience with async await.

I'm trying to create a mock for a service which returns data from a database.

The concrete service class can be slow, so the interface returns Task as shown below:

```
public interface IReferenceDataService
    {
        Task<List<ReferenceDataResults>> GetReferenceData(string domain, string concept);
    }
```

My mock class looks as follows:

```
public class MockReferenceDataService : IReferenceDataService
{
    public async Task<List<ReferenceDataResults>> GetReferenceData(string domain, string concept)
    {
        List<ReferenceDataResults> ret = new List<ReferenceDataResults>();

        var refDataRepo = new List<ReferenceDataResults>()
        {
            new ReferenceDataResults{ Domain = "Interfaces.Avaloq", Concept = "Client", Key1 = "CE", Value1 = "2", Key2 = "Avaloq", Value2 = "Individual" },
             new ReferenceDataResults{ Domain = "Interfaces.Avaloq", Concept = "Client", Key1 = "CE", Value1 = "3", Key2 = "Avaloq", Value2 = "Joint" } 

        };

        var found = refDataRepo.FindAll(x => x.Domain == domain && x.Concept == concept);

        foreach (var row in found)
        {
            ret.Add(new ReferenceDataResults() { Concept = row.Concept,
                Domain = row.Domain, Key1 = row.Key1, Key2 = row.Key2, Value1 = row.Value1, Value2 = row.Value2 });
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

This gives a compiler warning because it's marked as "async" yet lacks an "await". 
I guess the closest to the db retrieval is the FindAll method on the List but there doesn't seem to be an async version of FindaAll that I can "await".

What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: change the return statement to `return await Task.FromResult(ret);`. You can read the details about `Task.FromResult` at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @user1672994 I would recommend losing the `async` and the `await` and just use `return Task.FromResult(ret);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `async` does not form part of the interface, try just removing it:

```
public class MockReferenceDataService : IReferenceDataService
{
    public Task<List<ReferenceDataResults>> GetReferenceData(string domain, string concept)
    {
        // Your code
        return Task.FromResult(ret);
    }
}
```